Cognitive Behavioral Therapy vs Mindfulness meditation
I am currently practicing both CBT and mindfulness meditation. I find that they are definitionally incompatible.

CBT teaches one to analyze thoughts rationally, while noting cognitive distortions that affect that way we feel and our mood in general.
Mindfulness meditation simply tells us to note our thoughts, and watch them dissipate into nothingness, robbing them of meaning.

In the case of 1, we focus and analyze thoughts, while in 2, we try to simply let them go. Is this distinction valid?
